# Windows Timer in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am trying check if it is possible to show timer in a Textbox on click of a button. on button click the timer should start running and after the process is done I want to stop the timer. Below is what I have. What should I chnage to make it work?

```
public partial class MyClass: Form

{ 
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeTimer();      
}

private void InitializeTimer()
{  
    this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    // don't start timer until user clicks Start            
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    processingMessageTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { processingMessageTextBox.Text = "show running time after click"; }));
}       

private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Start();    
    doSomeTimeCOnsumingWork();
    this.timer1.Stop();    

}
```

}

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what the process is, and exactly what you want displayed in the text box?  So far your code appears valid, but all that will happen is every timer tick, the textbox text will be replaced with the same string.

Comment: Also, you are calling doSomeTimeConsumingWork() on the GUI thread, which will cause the GUI to become unresponsive until doSomeTimeConsumingWork() returns.  The invocation queued by the timer1_Tick method will wait behind the myButton_Click method.  You should investigate the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: I want the timer to keep running updating the processingMessageTextBox text with time and want it to stop once the  process is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another `Thread` (or `BackgroundWorker`) for updating the `TextBox` (or `Label`) with the elapsed time, until work is done.

And I would also use `Stopwatch` instead of `Timer` (easier to get the elapsed time).

**Code as follows;**

First, add this field:

```
private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
```

Now, add a `BackgroundWorker` to update the time.
In the `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` event, have this code, to keep update the appropriate `TextBox` or `Label` with the elapsed time:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (sw.IsRunning)
    {
        // Display elapsed time in seconds.
        processingMessageTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { processingMessageTextBox.Text = (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000).ToString(); }));
    }
}
```

Make sure that your `doSomeTimeCOnsumingWork` is running on **another thread**, so you won't block the UI.

You could use another `BackgroundWorker` for this purpose or just use `Thread` class.

In your `doSomeTimeCOnsumingWork` (you can create another BackgroundWorker for it) add the following:

```
private void doSomeTimeCOnsumingWork()
{
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    // Some work done here

    sw.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are dozen of errors methink.

`MyClass` is not the right name for the form.

No need to `Invoke` in the timer event (as its created in UI thread), simply do event

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    processingMessageLabel.Text = "show running time after click";
}
```

`myButton_Click` event performs all the job at once, blocking UI thread, make it more like this (to toggle `timer1`)

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
}
```

What else? You want to perform `doSomeTimeConsumingWork`? Why don't you use `Thread`, `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` for this?

Comment: In what way is `MyClass` not the right name?  He can name his `Forms` class anything he wants.

Comment: MyClass is not the actual name. I have pasted part of the code with a different class name.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `doSomeTimeConsumingWork()` happens on the GUI thread.  Windows Forms is single-threaded--what this means is that the timer will not be serviced until `doSomeTimeConsumingWork()` returns.  Furthermore, as another answer mentions, there's no need to use `Invoke` with a Windows Forms Timer, as it is already on the GUI thread.

Investigate the [`System.Windows.Forms.BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to put your time-consuming work on a separate thread.  `BackgroundWorker` includes a mechanism for reporting progress.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).